# Options for JavaScript within new window from Flash object?

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

We have an online product that is Flash only (SWF files). We can define zones in each Flash "page" as standard hyperlinks.

A client wants several hyperlinks in the Flash version to create a small "More info" popup window that adds details. I pointed these hyperlinks to HTML files that display an image and resize to fit the image size. That worked fine. Then we tried to make it center. We directed the hyperlink to an HTML page that created a temporary blank popup that triggered the image popup and added a centering command, then closed itself. Disaster in multiple browsers. So now, I want to know what options other than self-resizing JavaScript offers within an HTML file the browser has just loaded?

Comment: I can't completely tell what you are trying to do here. But if passing data from your SWF to the containing HTML? Using ExternalInterface within AS3 to call javascript functions in the containing page will help you with this.

Comment: Craig, the short version of the challenge is this: All JavaScript popup window customization has to happen within the one HTML file that is opened. The window.resizeTo works fine. I want to know about other options. I can pass some vars via the URL that opens the HTML.

Comment: PS I can't use ActionScript because the Flash files and the player that displays them are all locked in their existing format by our Development team. We have hundreds of publications online. Hence my focus on what can/can't be done inside an HTML file that is loaded.